# How to nest template strings in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings, template-literals

I got an `prefer-template` error from eslint. For the workaround, I changed my code to use a template string inside the `require` function which is nested inside the `url` function as following:

```
{
  background: `url(${require(`../../assets/${edge.node.name.toLowerCase()}.png` center no-repeat`)})
}
```

However, that gave an error, obviously. Here is the code I was using before, a plus sign concatenating inside the `require` function instead of the template string.

```
{
  background: `url(${require('../../assets/' + edge.node.name.toLowerCase() + '.png')}) center no-repeat`
}
```

Would it be possible to define nested template strings?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you had for some reason put the `)})` part (that closes the `require` call, the interpolated value, and the CSS `url`) in the wrong place:

```
{
  background: `url(${require(`../../assets/${edge.node.name.toLowerCase()}.png`)}) center no-repeat`
//                                                                             ^^^
}
```

That said, it's probably a bad idea as it doesn't exactly make the code readable. Better use a variable:

```
const bgurl = require(`../../assets/${edge.node.name.toLowerCase()}.png`);
… {
  background: `url(${bgurl}) center no-repeat`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That was my mistake for the demo. However, when I changed it to `url(${require(`../../assets/${edge.node.name.toLowerCase()}.png`)) center no-repeat` It's a syntax error.

Comment: @LVarayut: [Worksforme](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015&code=const%20x%20%3D%20{%0A%20%20background%3A%20%60url%28%24{require%28%60..%2F..%2Fassets%2F%24{edge.node.name.toLowerCase%28%29}.png%60%29}%29%20center%20no-repeat%60%0A}%3B). What error exactly are you getting?

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. Was my confusion about curly brackets. BTW, I'll go with your second approach.