# How to write Variable inside of Variable in Template String literal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object-literal, template-strings

`` log(`${chalk.magenta('  LAUNCH_COMMAND')} ${chalk.green('npm run: ')} ${chalk.red('${LAUNCH_COMMAND}')}` ); ``

Here is the problem part: `${chalk.red('${LAUNCH_COMMAND}')}`

`LAUNCH_COMMAND` is either 'production' or 'development'. However it's inside of another `${}`.

[image]

Comment: You absolutely should not [nest template strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36028061/1048572) if you want to keep your own sanity, and the code's readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/WZILF51203)</kbd>

Just use the Variable name for nested Variable in Template String literal

```
`${chalk.red(LAUNCH_COMMAND)}` // for nested sting literal just use the variable name
```

---

```
const LAUNCH_COMMAND = 'hi';
console.log(`${chalk.magenta('  LAUNCH_COMMAND')} ${chalk.green('npm run: ')} ${chalk.red(LAUNCH_COMMAND)}` );
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You don't wrap variables within string literals with quotes.

```
log(`${chalk.magenta(  LAUNCH_COMMAND)} ${chalk.green(npm run: )} ${chalk.red(LAUNCH_COMMAND})` );
```

^ Should hypothetically work though I'm not clear on the context behind why you're writing a string like this. I'm assuming it's some kind of dynamic output.

```js
var b = "Cats"
var c = "Dogs"

function concat(one, two) {

  return `${one} and ${two}`;

}

function compare(one, two) {

  var ans = one == two ? 'Are the same' : 'Are not the same';
  return ans;

}

console.log(`${concat(b, c)} - ${compare(b, c)}`);
```

Comment: @Bergi Oh but it does. See my edit, added a snippet.

Comment: No, try the first snippet. It produces a *SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token*.

Comment: The first snippet wasn't meant to run, I was just referencing it. My second snippet puts the principle into practice.

Comment: I appreciate it was a bad example, though. My apologies.

Comment: The problem is that the parameters to `magenta` and `green` are not *supposed* to be variables. They *need* to be string literals!