# Vue.js escape double colon

Tags: javascript, vue.js, escaping

The below shown code is written in *vue.js*.

Is there any possibility to create a **mailto**-link?
 Vue doesn't like the double colon `:` in `mailto:item.url` as it seems.

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  props: ['item'],
  template: `
    <div class="foo">
      <a v-bind:href="mailto:item.url">
        {{ item.url }}
      </a>
    </div>
  `
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vuejs didn't escape the double colon. what you write inside `v-bind:href="..."` is not a string, it's javascript code.

`mailto:item.url` is not a valid javascript code. so you had to construct a string using the language tools.

Another solution for constructing that string:

1. Use ES6 [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) - cleaner syntax.
2. You don't have to explicit declare `v-bind:href`. You can use the shorthand `:href`. this is more standard and more readable.

see the code:

```
<a :href="`mailto:${item.url}`">
```

## Edit 1

You put your entire `template` already inside `template string`. [It is possible  to nest template literal inside another template literal expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028061/how-to-nest-template-strings-in-es6).

weather your think using template literal will contribute to the readability of your code, it's up to personal taste.

Maybe the case is more debatable when you are using the simple form of template. 
When using the [webpack boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack), which has [`vue-loader`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) configured , it is much more readable.

Comment: `template`-Property is already using **Template Literals** in my code sample. How do we use **Template Literals** within **Template Literals** then?

Comment: added a reference to that comment in the answer. basically it is possible, and you can see a link to a another stackoverflow question asking it.

Answer (score 2):

Just found out by myself that the following code works:

```
v-bind:href="'mailto:' + item.mail"
```

Comment: This solution works if you are already inside Template Literals. Which is the case if you look at the question.